# postgresql how to update another table while on conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE people (
 name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 company_id int8 NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE company (
 id int8 NOT NULL,
);
```

I want to copy data from csv to DB. This is my script

```
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_company
                ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT * FROM company WITH NO DATA;
  \COPY tmp_company FROM 'company.csv' WITH CSV HEADER
                DELIMITER as ',';
  INSERT INTO company
                SELECT * FROM tmp_company
                ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

  CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_people
                ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT * FROM people WITH NO DATA;
  \COPY tmp_people FROM 'people.csv' WITH CSV HEADER
                DELIMITER as ',';
  INSERT INTO people
                SELECT * FROM tmp_people
                ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
COMMIT;
```

If existing company id is found in `company` table,
I should do company.id+=1 and replace the new company_id for the related `people` records.

Example:

```
company.csv
id
1
5

people.csv
name,company_id
tom,1
paul,5

existing company table data
id
1
2

existing people table data
name,company_id
tom,1
paul,2

After copying data from csv to DB, the data should look like

company table data
id
1
2
3 <-- from csv data, as 1,2 are used, set id=3
5

people table data
name,company_id
tom,1
paul,2
tom,3 <-- from csv data
paul,5 <-- from csv data
```

How can i do this? I am wondering if I can add the logic after `ON CONFLICT...`

Edit 1:
The two tables' size are near 5TBs.
and two csv contains 5M records.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use the `bigserial` data type instead of `int8` for the column id of the table `company` so that to automatically increase the id when inserting a new row.

Then, you should create a foreign key between your tables `people` and `company` with the option `ON UPDATE CASCADE` so that any change in the `id` column of the table `company` will be automatically propagated to the `company_id` column in the table `people`.

```
CREATE TABLE company (
 id bigserial NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE people (
 name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 company_id int8 NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT fkey FOREIGN KEY company_id REFERENCES company(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: I am dealing with legacy DB tables, I cannot change the table structure.